# Engine options for the 777-300ER: GE90-110B1 or -115B?

Tags: boeing-777

The [Wikipedia page on the Boeing 777](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777#Specifications) says that the 777-300ER can have either the GE90-110B1 or the GE90-115B, however it was my understanding that the 777-300ER does *not* have engine options and is only available with the GE90-115B.

Furthermore, [this](http://www.triple7-world.info/777prodline.pdf) unofficial production list confirms that there are no 777-300ER with the -110B1.

**With that said, here's my question:** has the 777-300ER ever been offered with the -110B1, whether as a factory option or as a retrofit/modification?

Comment: I updated the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777) to show the correct engines and thrust ratings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [EASA Type Certificate Data Sheet (TCDS)](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/TCDS_EASA%20IM%20A%20003_B777_%20Iss_15_2018-12-10.pdf) of the Boeing 777, only the GE90-115B engines are approved for the 777-300ER:

> **5. Engines:**
>
> Two (2) General Electrical GE90 Turbofan Engines
> Models installed: GE90-115B,
> EASA Type-Certificate No.: EASA.IM.E.002
> Limitations: See Engine Data Sheet No. EASA.IM.E.002

The GE90-110B1 model is listed for the Boeing 777-200LR and 777-200F models. In the Wikipedia table, the engine entry is for all of these models together.

Comment: The [GE90 spex table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GE90#Specifications) offers a hint as to why they're grouped together as well; same bigger fan and same compressor stages, for example.

Comment: @ymb1 Yes, it's pretty much the same engine with a higher thrust rating.